# Convert a matrix of value into a matrix of its cumulative product

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the cumulative product of a matrix, I will present my example below.

```
sample <- matrix(c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5),6,5,byrow=T)
sample
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    3    4    5
[2,]    1    2    3    4    5
[3,]    1    2    3    4    5
[4,]    1    2    3    4    5
[5,]    1    2    3    4    5
[6,]    1    2    3    4    5
```

I would like to compute the cumulative product for each row across each column. So the result should looks like:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    2    6   24  120
[2,]    1    2    6   24  120
[3,]    1    2    6   24  120
[4,]    1    2    6   24  120
[5,]    1    2    6   24  120
[6,]    1    2    6   24  120
```

I have tried cumprod(sample) and apparently it does not work well with matrix in this way, I am wondering if there is any shortcut to do this without using a loop.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Also, check this link <http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/matrix-row-product-and-cumulative-product-td841548.html>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
sample <- matrix(rep(1:5,6),ncol=5,byrow=TRUE)
```

(it may not be wise to use `sample` as a variable name, since it's also the name of a built-in function; it *is* wise to spell out `TRUE` rather than using the `T` shortcut)

This does it:

```
t(apply(sample,1,cumprod))
```

`apply(...,1,cumprod)` applies the `cumprod` function to each row ("2" would apply it to columns).  Because of the way that `apply` arranges its results:

> If each call to ‘FUN’ returns a vector of length ‘n’, then ‘apply’ returns an array of dimension ‘c(n, dim(X)[MARGIN])’ if ‘n > 1’.

you have to transpose (`t()`) the results.